# Primality criterion for Mersenne numbers involving Euler's totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples, primality-test, mersenne-numbers

I am looking for a proof of the following claim:

> Let $M_p=2^p-1$ where $p$ is a prime . Denote [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) by $\varphi(n)$ . Then,
> $$M_p \text{ is prime iff } \varphi(M_p) \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$$

The SageMath cell that demonstrates this claim can be found [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrsDWy5spM0_DNT9FILc1JLSrIyNQwiivQNdTUMdG0tTXSKSjKzCvRUAJSualKmjBucn5uQX5xZglQSNMaAO93FdY=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==). I have checked  claim for all $p$ below $260$. Clearly, if $M_p$ is prime we have $M_p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ and since $\varphi(q)=q-1$ for any prime $q$ it follows that  $\varphi(M_p) \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ . But how to prove this claim in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $2^p-1$ is composite, then it is not a prime power by Mihăilescu's theorem. Let $q,r\mid 2^p-1$ be two distinct prime factors, then both $q$ and $r$ are odd, whence $\varphi(q)$ and $\varphi(r)$ are both even. It follows that
$$4\mid\varphi(q)\varphi(r)=\varphi(qr)\mid \varphi(2^p-1).$$